# SQL Group By on consecutive rows only

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

So I have a table which looks like:

```
SITE      LOWER   UPPER   SIZE
a.com     0.1     0.2     10
a.com     0.2     0.3     10
a.com     0.3     0.4     10
a.com     0.7     0.8     10
a.com     0.9     1.0     10
b.com     0.1     0.2     20
a.com     0.6     0.7     30
```

My desired output would be:

```
SITE      LOWER   UPPER   SIZE
a.com     0.1     0.4     10
a.com     0.7     1.0     10
b.com     0.1     0.2     20
a.com     0.6     0.7     30
```

So for a `SITE` and `SIZE` pair, I need to compress `LOWER` and `UPPER` values where `LOWER` of the grouped by row is the minimum of the first row and `UPPER` is the maximum of the last row.`LOWER` and `UPPER` are like lower and upper bound values of some buckets (e.g. [0.1, 0.2]) and I only need consecutive buckets to be compressed together. Any help would be much appreciated in this regard.

Comment: Please tag your question with the version of MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a group id to the adjacent rows using variables:

```
select t.*,
        (@grp := IF(@sru = CONCAT_WS(':', site, rev, lower), 
                    IF(@sru := CONCAT_WS(':', site, rev, upper), @grp, @grp),
                    IF(@sru := CONCAT_WS(':', site, rev, upper) , @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                   )
            ) as grp
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by site, size, lower
     ) cross join
     (select @grp := 0, @sru := '') params;
```

You can then aggregate to get what you want:

```
select site, size, min(lower) as lower, max(upper) as upper
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := IF(@sru = CONCAT_WS(':', site, rev, lower), 
                         IF(@sru := CONCAT_WS(':', site, rev, upper), @grp, @grp),
                         IF(@sru := CONCAT_WS(':', site, rev, upper) , @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                        )
             ) as grp
      from (select t.*
            from t
            order by site, size, lower
           ) cross join
           (select @grp := 0, @sru := '') params
     ) t
group by size, size, grp;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dfed4/18) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I tried your solution the other day and it worked just fine. Now that I am trying it again here:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dfed4/1 it is just returning all rows and not grouped together. Could you help me to sort this out?

Comment: @ahajib . . . This is trickier than I thought at first.  The variable that stores the grouping information (was `@ssu`, now `@sru`) needs to adjust to the new upper limit each time through.