# How to select multiple date ranges + another value and group by each range

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a query that will find date ranges and group them together with another value. The datetime inserted can range between seconds or days between each one.

It will be in a stored procedure on a MySQL server running version 8.

My table looks something like this:

```
inserted            |   ref_id   |   state
2019-09-16 18:01:00 |   1        |   0
2019-09-16 18:02:00 |   1        |   0
2019-09-16 18:03:00 |   1        |   1
2019-09-16 18:04:00 |   1        |   1
2019-09-16 18:05:00 |   1        |   0
2019-09-16 18:06:00 |   1        |   0
2019-09-16 18:01:00 |   2        |   1
2019-09-16 18:02:00 |   2        |   1
2019-09-16 18:03:00 |   2        |   1
```

Create table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  inserted DATETIME NULL,
  ref_id INT NULL,
  state TINYINT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO my_table 
    (inserted, ref_id, state) 
VALUES 
    ("2019-09-16 18:01:00", 1, 0),
    ("2019-09-16 18:02:00", 1, 0),
    ("2019-09-16 18:03:00", 1, 1),
    ("2019-09-16 18:04:00", 1, 1),
    ("2019-09-16 18:05:00", 1, 0),
    ("2019-09-16 18:06:00", 1, 0),
    ("2019-09-16 18:01:00", 2, 1),
    ("2019-09-16 18:02:00", 2, 1),
    ("2019-09-16 18:03:00", 2, 1)
```

Desired output (where ref_id = 1):

```
from                |   to                    |   state
2019-09-16 18:01:00 |   2019-09-16 18:02:00   |   0
2019-09-16 18:03:00 |   2019-09-16 18:04:00   |   1
2019-09-16 18:05:00 |   2019-09-16 18:06:00   |   0
```

Comment: @Barmar - Sorry, I don't think it's the same question. In my case the time between is not fixed, it could be seconds, hours or multiple days.

Comment: Why is there no group for `18:02:01 to 18:02:59`, `18:04:01-18:04:59'`, etc?

Comment: I think the third answer in the linked question should be usable. Just replace `7200` with a procedure parameter that specifies the size of the range in seconds.

Comment: There is no "inserted" that begins at `18:02:01`

Comment: But the range is not known in advance. It could be one second for one row and 2 days for the next

Comment: How are the ranges determined? Are you just grouping consecutive rows that have the same state?

Comment: Yes, exactly. My problem is creating a value that I can group by, because the datetime can vary.

Comment: Here are some other questions closer to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317206/mysql-group-by-consecutive-rows?r=SearchResults&s=2|98.5286 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445989/sql-group-by-on-consecutive-rows-only?r=SearchResults&s=3|88.4256

Comment: It looks like you are trying to find the `inserted` values where the state doesn't match the previous state. With that you can know the ranges when state had a cintinuous value. Does that sound like what you are looking for?

Comment: @Jerry - Yes, that sounds about right. Sorry, if I haven't been clear enough in the question.